# Set items of array by index Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I have a Mongoose Schema that looks something like this

```
var aSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    id: String,
    registered: [{
        user: String,
        priority: String,
        id: String
    }]
});
```

I want to have 14 items inside the `registered` property and expect to be able to set them individually. When a user submits a form, I'm querying/updating the collection like so

```
aSchema.findOneAndUpdate({id: some_id}, {
        type: 'a type',
        id: 'an id'
    },
    { upsert: true },
    function (err, model)
    {
        var endIndex = 4;
        var startIndex = 2;

        for (i=startIndex;i<endIndex;i++)
        {
            model.registered[i] = {
                user: req.session.user,
                priority: req.body.priority,
                id: req.body.token
            }
        }

        model.save(function ()
        {
            //Do some more
        });
   }
);
```

When I run a variation of the above code, I get

```
doc.validate(function (err) {
    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'validate'
```

I assume that this is because of the odd thing I'm trying to do with the array. Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: Try replacing `model.registered[i] = {...}` with `model.registered.set(i, {...})`.

Comment: Thanks! I think it was a combination of that and my using the reserved "type" as a key.